# GLOM of a launch vehicle

Tags: rockets, terminology, launch-vehicle

What do you mean by GLOM of a launch vehicle? When I googled about it, it says it is a type of mass but I am unclear about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GLOM = Gross Lift-Off Mass. [This is](https://www.oxfordreference.com/view/10.1093/oi/authority.20110803095909364)

> The overall weight of a spacecraft at lift-off, including the main rocket, boosters, propellant, and payload.

Comment: Thankyou Hobbes